# Letting a child control width size to fit and limiting its max value

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, textbox

Edit: I try rephrasing my question, sorry if it was not clear. Thanks to all anyway.

Say I have a UserControl whose layout has a grid with 1 row x 3 columns, the first 2 autosized and the third star-sized:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="150" .../>
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top".../>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" MaxHeight="400" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"...>
</Grid>
```

The TextBox has text wrapping and its vertical scrollbar visibility set to auto and its horizontal one hidden.

Now, I have some window including a ListBox whose items are instances of this UserControl, like:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch".../>
```

The ListBox is in a 1-column star-sized grid and thus stretches to fit all the available width in its container. When I resize the container of this ListBox the ListBox too resizes as expected as it is stretched in a star-sized Grid column; and the same holds true for the ListBox items', which too are stretched and in this case happen to be instances of a UserControl with the above layout (3 columns in a grid, the 3rd star-sized).

The problem is that the TextBox in the 3rd column of the UserControl used as a listbox item should not automatically increase its width when I type into it some long text: it should just wrap, increasing its height (up to a maximum height; then the vertical scrollbar will appear). In other words, its MaxWidth should be determined by the available space, like its Width.

How should I code my XAML for this?

Comment: Post the XAML with the ListBox.   And just how do expect to resize you ListBox with a mouse if is it in a grid?

Comment: Sorry probably I did not explain myself clearly. The ListBox has just its ItemsSource set to an observable collection of UserControl's, e.g. <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="..."/>. The TextBox HorizontalAlignment is Stretch and as such it works.The problem is that it keeps enlarging its width whenever I type a lengthy text: I should constrain its MaxWidth according to the available space so that it wraps rather than enlarging. As for mouse-resize,I meant resizing the main window which includes the Grid which includes (in its star-sized col) the stretched TextBox.Thx!

Comment: And you still have not posted the XAML for the ListBox.

Comment: Sorry :), the XAML is in my comment: it's just that, a ListBox with a horizontal content alignment=stretch.

Comment: "Now, I have some window including a ListBox."  Show the XAML.  Show the 1-column star-sized grid.  If you are having problems with sizing then you need to post the entire XAML.

Comment: Here is a complete fake solution which reproduces the issue: http://www.filesonic.com/file/4321601775/Repro.zip . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

That should be the behavior by default, based on the code you've posted.

Try setting your TextBox's `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`